# How would I randomize an int[][]?

Tags: java

I'm making a game in Java and need to randomize the order of the board. Below is the code for what I am doing:

```
public static int[] RandomizeArray(int[] array){
    Random rgen = new Random();     

    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        int randomPosition = rgen.nextInt(array.length);
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[randomPosition];
        array[randomPosition] = temp;
    }

    return array;
}

public void startNewGame(){
       numTries = 0;
       won = false;
       board = new int[4][4];

       RandomizeArray(board);
       for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++){

           for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++){

               board[row][col] = (row+1) + (4 * col);
           } 
       }


   repaint();
}
```

Right now Java is telling me that "int[] cannot be converted to int[][]," but I am unsure why. Any help would be great.

Comment: Your code is using a 2D array, not an `ArrayList`. You should be more precise in your terminology.

Answer (score 2):

`board` is a 2-dimensional `int[][]` but `RandomizeArray` expects a 1-dimensional `int[]`. You'll need to change `RandomizeArray` to work in two dimensions.

Comment: You'll need something like the nested `for` loops in `startNewGame`.

Comment: Alternatively, you might need to call `RandomizeArray` on each row of the `board` array, rather than randomizing the entire array.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is because you're trying to pass in a 2D array instead of a 1D array. For example, if you said `RandomizeArray(board[0]);`, that would be a valid argument.

Or, you could change your `RandomizeArray` method to:

```
public static int[] RandomizeArray(int[][] array) {
   ...
}
```

Note the additional `[]` in my argument. If you went this route you would need to rework your logic for randomizing.

Also, even if you were successfully calling your `RandomizeArray()` method, you're rearranging your blank values, and then filling them with new values later on, thereby defeating your purpose to begin with.

**Here is my approach to the problem.**

The Collections class has a built shuffle method. Let's take advantage of that. Here is a full example.

```
public void startNewGame() {
        int boardSize = 4;
        numTries = 0;
        won = false;
        board = new int[boardSize][boardSize];
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList();

        for (int row = 0; row < boardSize; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < boardSize; col++) {
                        temp.add((row + 1) + (boardSize * col));
                }        
        }

        Collections.shuffle(temp);

        for (int row = 0; row < boardSize; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < boardSize; col++) {
                        board[row][col] = temp.get(row * boardSize + col);
                }        
        }

        repaint();
}
```